# Generate list combinations in Python - with rules

Tags: python, combinations, python-itertools

I have two list:

```py
list1 = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]
list2 = ["AA", "BB", "CC", "DD", "EE"]
```

I want to create every possible combination, as the following:

```
    A-B-C-D-E
    A-BB-C-D-E
    A-B-C-DD-E...etc.
```

The rule is that two similar letter (like A-AA, B-BB) can't be in the combination at the same time, and the order is reversible (A-B-C-D-E and B-A-E-C-D is the same in content so i don't need them both)

How can I manage it with itertools?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you want. If I understand you correctly, you want, given two lists `a` and `b` of length of `N`, to create `N` lists of length `N`, such that the `i`th list is a copy of list `a`, but with the `i`th entry replaced with the `i`th entry of list `b`? Is the omission of `AA-B-C-D-E` and `A-B-CC-D-E` intentional?

Comment: Can `A-BB-CC-D-E` be in the output? Your sample output makes me assume that at most only one item of two character list is allowed for a given item.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TL;DR: `map('-'.join, product(*zip(list1, list2)))`.

---

It's relatively simple to do using `itertools`, but you have to think through each step carefully.

First, you can zip your two lists together to get a sequence of tuples. Every element in your final result will include exactly one choice from each tuple.

```
>>> list1 = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]
>>> list2 = ["AA", "BB", "CC", "DD", "EE"]
>>> list(zip(list1, list2))
[('A', 'AA'), ('B', 'BB'), ('C', 'CC'), ('D', 'DD'), ('E', 'EE')]
```

Next, we'll want the Cartesian product of each of the five tuples. This gives us the 32 different ways of choosing one of A or AA, then one of B or BB, etc. To do that, we use `*` to unpack the result of `zip` into five separate arguments for `product`.

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> for x in product(*zip(list1, list2)):
...   print(x)
...
('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E')
('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'EE')
('A', 'B', 'C', 'DD', 'E')
('A', 'B', 'C', 'DD', 'EE')
('A', 'B', 'CC', 'D', 'E')
('A', 'B', 'CC', 'D', 'EE')
('A', 'B', 'CC', 'DD', 'E')
# etc
```

Once you have the product, each element of the product is a valid argument to `'-'.join` to create one of the strings in your desired set:

```
>>> for x in map('-'.join, product(*zip(list1, list2))):
...   print(x)
...
A-B-C-D-E
A-B-C-D-EE
A-B-C-DD-E
A-B-C-DD-EE
A-B-CC-D-E
A-B-CC-D-EE
A-B-CC-DD-E
A-B-CC-DD-EE
A-BB-C-D-E
A-BB-C-D-EE
A-BB-C-DD-E
A-BB-C-DD-EE
A-BB-CC-D-E
A-BB-CC-D-EE
A-BB-CC-DD-E
A-BB-CC-DD-EE
AA-B-C-D-E
AA-B-C-D-EE
AA-B-C-DD-E
AA-B-C-DD-EE
AA-B-CC-D-E
AA-B-CC-D-EE
AA-B-CC-DD-E
AA-B-CC-DD-EE
AA-BB-C-D-E
AA-BB-C-D-EE
AA-BB-C-DD-E
AA-BB-C-DD-EE
AA-BB-CC-D-E
AA-BB-CC-D-EE
AA-BB-CC-DD-E
AA-BB-CC-DD-EE
```